# Mule variable declaration using set-payload vs expression component

Tags: mule

From this SO question [Mule expression variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294001/mule-expression-variable-scope), I understood that:

- variables declared using set-payload are like instance variables.
- variables defined in expression component are like method local variables.

Is my understanding correct? How do we access variables inside expression component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong in your question..
You cannot declare a variable using set-payload...  set-payload are used to override existing message payload ..
You can set variable using `<set-variable>`

Now back to your question .. 
Yes there are 2 types of variable in Mule :-

- Flow Variables
- Session Variables

If you use **Flow variable**, it is an instance variable.. the scope of the variable is **INVOCATION** .. that is limited to a particular Flow (and sub-flow)
where as if you use **Session Variables** .. It's scope is **Global** and can access from any flow in the configuration

So now .. as I said you can declare a variable using `<set-variable>` .. here during declaring the variable you need to declare it's **scope** ... That is either **INVOCATION** or **SESSION**

Similarly if you declare a variable using expression component you need to declare the variable either as **INVOCATION** or **SESSION**

for example .. see the following :-

```
<set-session-variable variableName="sessionId" value="#[message.id+’@’+mule.nodeId]" />
<expression-component>sessionVars.sessionId = message.id+'@'+mule.nodeId;</expression-component>
```

Here you are setting variable using both `<set-variable>` and **Expression Component**

and you are setting here as a **Global** or you can say as a **Session** Variable

Please find the following for your reference :-
http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-school-the-mulemessage-property-scopes-and-variables/

**UPDATED ANSWER:-**

Yes .You can set the variable either in set-variable or expression and you can access the variable anywhere and it doesn't matter where you have declared ..

For example if you want access the **session variables** in **Expression component** that you have declared in set-session-variable using the following :-  `<set-session-variable variableName="sessionId" value="#[message.id+’@’+mule.nodeId]" />`  .....

you can do the following :-

set the session variable into payload `<expression-component>payload=sessionVars.sessionId;</expression-component>`

and then you can print payload using logger :-

`<logger message="payload with sessionVars:-#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>`
 to check the value

Comment: The wrong in the question is a typo. My intention is to ask about, `set-variable vs expression-component`. You have cleared my doubt. Can we access a variable declared using set-variable, inside expression-component?

Comment: Thank you man. Can't I declare/set a variable in `expression-component` and use it some where in the flow?

Comment: Yes that what I said .. you can set it anywhere and can access it from any where within it's scope .. if you use session variable it's scope is through out all the flows .. and if you use flow variables you can access it within the flow anywhere .. so as per your question if you set the session variable in expression-component you can access it in Mule flow using Mule expression language .. for example in logger :- `<logger message="session variables #[sessionVars['sessionId']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>`